# Remove loop if present in the Linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to write code that can remove the loop from the linked list, if any in the list.

```
Input:
N = 3 //total number of nodes in the list
value[] = {1,3,4}
C = 2 //position of the last connected node, if it is zero it is not connected
Output: 1
```

---

```
void removeLoopLlinkedList(Node* head)
{
    if(!head) return;
    
    Node* first= head->next;
    Node* last= head;  
    
    while( first!= last)
    {
        if( !first|| !last->next ) return;
        first=first->next->next;
        last=last->next;
    }
    
    int size = 1;
    first = first->next;
    while( first== last)
    {
        size++;
        first= first->next;
    }
    
    
    first= head;
    for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++)
        first= first->next;
    
    while( last->next != last )
    {
        first= first->next;
        last= last->next;
    }
}
```

I can not find my errors and not getting the desired output. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code in a debugger (possibly while using pen and paper to visualize the list and the changes made)? How do you create the list? How do you call the function? How do you check the result? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your program (with emphasis on the *minimal* part, hard-coding "input" is okay).

Comment: A comment on code style: you have numerous, inconsistent formatting styles in your code. It's better to choose an appropriate style (some [examples](https://developer.gnome.org/programming-guidelines/stable/c-coding-style.html.en)), and stick to it.

Comment: what do you mean by remove loops? self-loops? cycles? and what are you supposed to replace it for?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, but I assume that 'C' refers to the number of the node (counting from 1) that the final node in the list points to, and that "removing the loop" means searching from the start of the loop to find the node that is looped back to (if any) and chop off the entire loop from the list. Presumably it ought to return two lists - the initial portion (if any) and the looped portion (if any). Note that the loop could be the entire list.